# Trying to binary search

Tags: c, binary-search

I am trying to binary search a string from a struct of arrays. I keep getting a segmentation fault or an infinite loop. I was wondering what I am doing wrong.

```
int binsearch(struct person d[25], int low_int, int high_int, char search[15])
{
    int mid_int;
    printf(".");

    mid_int = ((high_int - low_int)/2);
    mid_int = mid_int + low_int;

    if(strcmp(search, d[mid_int].name) == 0)
        return mid_int;

    if(low_int > high_int)
        return -1;
    else if(strcmp(search, d[mid_int].name) > 0)
    {
        binsearch(d, mid_int+1, high_int, search);
    }
    else
    {
        binsearch(d, low_int, mid_int-1, search);
    }
}
```

Whenever I add in the "mid_int = mid_int + low_int" it gives me a straight segmentation error. Where as when I take it away it goes on an infinite loop printing "....." then resulting in a segmentation fault (the periods are to show how many loops it takes for the search).

Comment: Why not step through the code in your debugger to see what's going on ?

Comment: seems like  `return` is missing  `return binsearch(...`

Comment: Efficiency idea: save the result of `strcmp(search, d[mid_int].name)`, no need to call it twice.

Comment: @sukurity If my answer has solver your question please consider accepting it by clicking the green check-mark next to the answer. This will indicate to the community that you have found a solution and gives some reputation to both you and me.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you will have to use the `return` keyword on the recursive `binsearch()` calls if you want to get any result out of them.

Then make the if `if(low_int > high_int)` check before accessing the struct array so you don't access elements out of bounds.

Assuming you are calling the function with valid parameters, the code should work.

```
binsearch( d , 0 , d_size-1 , "Search" ) ;
```

Note that the the function definition:

```
int binsearch(struct person d[25], int low_int, int high_int, char search[15])
```

is equivalent to

```
int binsearch(struct person d[], int low_int, int high_int, char search[])
```

Those sizes 25 and 15 don't do anything in this case. You will have to pass the size of your arrays. This is already handled by `low_int`, `high_int` for `d` and `search` should be nul terminated since it is a string.

Comment: Right on the `if(low_int > high_int)` part and the need for `return`.  Also `mid_int = ((high_int - low_int)/2); mid_int = mid_int + low_int;` could be `mid_int = (mid_int + low_int)/2;`